# Is there any way to use LaTex formulas in a programming language to make a real calculation

Tags: javascript, python, latex, julia

We may write down the calculation formula of a distance measurement with the following LaTex string:

```
dist_{12} = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 }
dist_{13} = \sqrt{ z_{33}^2 + y^2 }

total = dist_{12} + dist_{13}
```

This looks good so far. If I really need to make a computer calculate these equations, then I need the following - eg. Python - code:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z_33 = 3
dist_12 = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
dist_13 = sqrt(z_33**2 + y**2)
total = dist_12 + dist_13
print "Total distance is: ", total
```

As a result, I spent as twice as the effort actually needed.

However, if there was a way to use exact same LaTex formula (which may include integrals, derivatives, limits etc.) in a programming language (preferably Python, Javascript and Julia) we would re-use our efforts later in our real-world applications.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: Yes. Write a bunch of software to parse the TeX source and generate code in the target languages of your choice.

Comment: Or you could also use Unicode with Julia and write code with mathematical symbols. Use `\symbolname<TAB>` to input them at the REPL and several other Julian environments, ie. type `\<TAB><TAB>` to see auto completion suggestions for all the possible symbols, or `dist\_1<TAB>\_2<TAB>` for `dist₁₂` and `\_sqrt<TAB>` for `√` (it is an alias for the Julia`sqrt` generic function). Your example could look like this: `julia> x, y, z₃₃ = rand(3); dist₁₂ = √(x^2 + y^2); dist₁₃ = √(z₃₃^2 + y^2); total = dist₁₂ + dist₁₃` (since the question was closed Idid a one liner), I think it's pretty neat! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

1. Use [latex2sympy](https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy) to translate latex equations to SymPy objects
2. Just use [SymPy printing tools](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html) to get the same equations as latex

Both alternatives avoid you having to re-type the equations.